# How to set composer flag --ignore-platform-reqs for Amazon AWS deployment

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony 3 app on Amazon AWS Elastic beanstalk. I'm creating a folder .ebextentions in root dir. In this dir I'm add a composer.config file which contains such code:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
    composer_options: --no-dev --ignore-platform-reqs
```

But eb-engine.log is telling me

[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction

I am using
PHP 8.0 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.4 of aws beanstalk

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

So I just ran a similar command and it worked fine for me. The only difference between what you have and what I have is the quotations. So I think it should be:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:"
    composer_options: --no-dev --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: The " is meant to be before the :